# Microphone array in Windows 10 resets to 0 and gets muted

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

When I set my microphone array to 100 and un-mute it a few seconds later it resets to 0 and the mic gets muted. I have tried everything I know to do:

- Disabled the mic
- Set up the mic 4 or 5 times
- Restarted my computer
- Disabled applications to take control of my mic

I am using Panasonic earbuds that have been working for the past 4 years and I just got the SADES gaming headset.

I've read posts from other people who struggle with the same thing and saw they couldn't really resolve it. How can I keep my microphone from resetting to 0 and muting?